# How to git pull a branch if remote and local commits history differs?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, workflow

Let's say I have been working on a project and at 08:41:11 have pushed my branch to the remote repository's branch (origin/feature/server-java).

git log of my local repo and the remote repo (origin/feature-server-java) look like:

```
92x301b Change to Server java 08:41:11
91881cc Remove Server GO 08:01:10
5f11b11 Change to yaml config 07:50:55
5f462ff Remove json config 07:10:55
7119093 Remove old config 06:30:33
13829ac New Client URL 06:10:40
```

Then some of the experienced developers pulled the project and made changes (squashed and deleted some commits) to git commits' history, afterwards he --force pushed that changes to the same remote branch (origin/feature/server-java).

Now remote repo (origin/feature/server-java) looks like (by 10:50:10):

```
32122ae Add Server 10:50:10
fff5223 Add config yaml 09:50:55
23cc544 Change Client URL 09:10:40
```

These commit history changes haven't changed source code at all (all tests are still passed as before). But now I wish to git pull that origin/feature/server-java with this changed history. How would I do this? My goal is to completely override the existing my local git commits' history with the remote one.

Seems, that `git pull --no-ff origin feature/server-java` doesn't help.

Comment: Why doesn't that last command help?

Comment: @mkrieger1 a) it forces me to create "merge commit" (it is ok) b) it still adds some locally made commits to the commits history when git log (let's say I have made some tiny changes at 11:00:01, but I still wish to have commits history as on remote branch at 10:50;10)

Comment: Re: a) Well you told it so by `--no-ff`. You could have used a different option, e.g. `--rebase`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fetch first:

```
git fetch origin
```

Then `origin/feature/server-java` should be up-to-date with what's in the server. Normally you would want to do `git merge` or `git rebase`, but if you are sure you don't want any of your local changes, just do:

```
git reset --hard origin/feature/server-java
```

Now your branch will be exactly the same as the remote branch.

Comment: But it's a good habit to get into to use fetch instead of pull, especially when you're going to do operations like this one.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I know, but the next time something like this happens it's better to do `git fetch` first. I wrote a whole blog post about why `git pull` should not be used: https://felipec.wordpress.com/2021/07/13/why-is-git-pull-broken/

Comment: @mkrieger1 I guess here is no difference whether to use fetch or pull, "reset --hard" does that commit history align, I guess

Comment: `git pull` is essentially `git fetch` + `git merge`, except the order of the parents is almost always wrong, unless you have configured it to do `git rebase` instead of `git merge`. But in this case the user does **not** want to merge, therefore the user should not call `git pull`.